# Passing `missing` argument to a bernoulli model in Turing.jl

Tags: julia, bayesian, probabilistic-programming

Turing.jl has a [guide](https://turing.ml/dev/docs/using-turing/guide) that shows how to write a model that allows you to either pass data or a `missing` argument. In the first case it will get you the posterior, in the second case, instead, it will draw from all the variables.

Setup

```
using Turing
iterations = 1000
ϵ = 0.05
τ = 10
```

The working example is like this:

```
@model gdemo(x, ::Type{T} = Float64) where {T} = begin
    if x === missing
        # Initialize `x` if missing
        x = Vector{T}(undef, 2)
    end
    s ~ InverseGamma(2, 3)
    m ~ Normal(0, sqrt(s))
    for i in eachindex(x)
        x[i] ~ Normal(m, sqrt(s))
    end
end

# Construct a model with x = missing
model = gdemo(missing)
c = sample(model, HMC(0.01, 5), 500);
```

I tried to adapt this code to a simple coin flip. The `bernoulli` distribution, I think, should have data type `Bool` (I tried with `Int64` too though). I tried doing this:

```
@model coinflip2(y) = begin
    if y === missing
        y = Vector{Bool}(undef, 4)
    end
    p ~ Beta(1, 1)
    N = length(y)
    for n in 1:N
        y[n] ~ Bernoulli(p)
    end
end;

chain = sample(coinflip2(missing), HMC(ϵ, τ), iterations);
```

But it gave me a long error message I don't get but quite likely point to a type problem:

```
MethodError: Bool(::ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{Turing.Core.var"#f#7"{DynamicPPL.VarInfo{NamedTuple{(:p, :y),Tuple{DynamicPPL.Metadata{Dict{DynamicPPL.VarName{:p,Tuple{}},Int64},Array{Beta{Float64},1},
```

Trying to mimic the syntax from the working `gdemo` function above (which I don't fully get), gives you:

```
@model coinflip2(y, ::Type{T} = Bool) where {T} = begin
    if y === missing
        y = Vector{T}(undef, 4)
    end
    p ~ Beta(1, 1)
    N = length(y)
    for n in 1:N
        y[n] ~ Bernoulli(p)
    end
end;

chain = sample(coinflip2(missing), HMC(ϵ, τ), iterations);
```

which also fails with an error message that starts with:

```
MethodError: Bool(::ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{Turing.Core.var"#f#7"{DynamicPPL.VarInfo{NamedTuple{(:p, :y),Tuple{DynamicPPL.Metadata{Dict{DynamicPPL.VarName{:p,Tuple{}},Int64},Array{Beta{Float64},1}
```

How do I write this correctly? Bonus points for explaining what I'm doing wrong :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hamiltonian Monte Carlo works only on continuous distributions, since it differentiates a function of the PDF.  When you sample from the joint model, `(p, y)`, this also applies to the random variable `y`, which, being Bernoulli, is certainly *not* continuous.  Hence, the AD system used in the background (`ForwardDiff` by default) will complain.

You can solve this by specifying a non-Hamiltonian sampler for `y` using [`Gibbs`](https://turing.ml/dev/docs/library/#Turing.Inference.Gibbs):

```
chain = sample(coinflip2(missing), Gibbs(HMC(ϵ, τ, :p), MH(:y)), iterations)
```

MH might not be the best choice, you'd have to think about that yourself, but it works.

Note that is not necessary for parameter estimation: just `p` given `y` is continuous and makes HMC happy:

```
chain = sample(coinflip2([0,1,1,0]), HMC(ϵ, τ), iterations)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you include in your answer something about the type notation in `coinflip2(y, ::Type{T} = Int64) where {T}`? I tried with different types and it still works. I'm guessing it only helps for speed (with type stability)? I don't understand the type of which variable is it declaring...is it the returning object? The type of the distribution I'm sampling from? Or is it just a placeholder `T` that may or not be used somewhere in the definition of the function?
(As an aside `rand(Bernoulli(0.3), 1)` gives me `1-element Array{Bool,1}`, not an `Int`)

Comment: Yeah, it's for type stability, by fixing the content type of the observations (which can be `Missing`), see [here](https://turing.ml/dev/docs/using-turing/performancetips#make-your-model-type-stable). And about the support of `Bernoulli`: right, it seems the docs of Distributions are outdated. I have to look this up every time as well.

Comment: What if I write `coinflip2(y, ::Type{T} = Int64) where {T}` but then never use that `T` within the definition of the function. Does it still indicate to the compiler that something is `Int64` or it won't change a thing until I use it somewhere in the body of the function? (sorry for the extra questions! I think a quick line or two about this would benefit your answer for the other readers)

Comment: If it is not used, it does not make a difference. But the type stability comes from special handling by the DynamicPPL compiler, not from what Julia usually does (have a look at `matchingvalue` in the macro expansion of the model). I don't really understand it completely myself :)